# Errors in mlr3 package using "surv.rfsrc" as a learner

Tags: survival-analysis, mlr3

When I try to running survival randomforest model in mlr3 using codes as below:

```
data(veteran)
veteran.xgb <- veteran[, !(names(veteran) %in% c("celltype"))]

set.seed(1369)

train = sample(nrow(veteran.xgb), 0.5 * nrow(veteran.xgb))
test = setdiff(seq(nrow(veteran.xgb)), train)

task = TaskSurv$new("RFSCRC_VET", backend = veteran.xgb, time = "time", event = "trt")
learn = lrn("surv.rfsrc")

learn$train(task, row_ids = train)
```

And the errors happened, Error: pv$codes %??% -1L, and suggests that there is no `%??%` in R. Was it a bug?

Comment: Can you produce a reprex? So include all the packages you have loaded so this can be reproduced. But also try adding `library(mlr3); library(mlr3misc); library(mlr3learners); library(mlr3proba)` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This is a bug in mlr3extralearners which will be fixed soonish.

Comment: For now just make sure you include `library(checkmate)` at the start of your code.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, the learner I want to use is `learn = lrn("surv.rfsrc") `. And WOW, after library(checkmate), it works! Thank you very much for your helpful advice!!